# Javascript that will run only one one domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, vs-web-site-project

I would like to create some javascript that will only run on a given domain.  We want to give each of our subscribers a bit of javascript that they can only run on their domain.  The javascript will create an iFrame and bring in a page, etc.

If the javascript is placed on a different domain, an error is thrown and the script stops and the iFrame page will not load.   Before you say this is not possible, it is done by Google Maps.

So, in short, we would like to mimic what Google Maps is doing.  You register a domain with Google, they give you code that has a key and if you place this code on any other domain, it will not work.   How do they do it?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say that the (GoogleMaps) JS does run everywhere. However, the server-side API it calls probably doesn't return data unless they API key matches the domain to which it has been registered.

Comment: Your JavaScript would have to make some kind of sever side validation. Anything you do purely in JS can be faked out by the person running your JS code on their page

Answer (score 0):

The `hostname` property of `window.location` contains a hostname. It can be faked, so you could try checking the `Referer` header when serving your script, too – but absolutely **do not** rely on that.

You could also do a bit of a validity check by making a request to a nonexistent page on that domain – it’ll be blocked by cross-origin policies if the developer is cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use the IP address, since the code is placed on a server.
I've made an license script with this method, and so far only 2 mad customers, but that was because they moved their website to another server without me telling it.

I think its good to have a client check, but that can be by-passed, if someone figures out how the script works. So, always do a server-side check.

Here is some code I use for the license check, its server based. 
Also, I removed some functions that are specific to my website. 
I can't figure out how to post code so I put it on pastebin.
http://pastebin.com/ftEDXhTP

Answer (score 0):

When you give the user their snippet of code, on the server-side, store a specific domain name with an identifier you give to the user. You will likely generate this code automatically, like StackOverflow did with your question. They called it `19850979`, so let's use that as the identifier you give to your user for example. When the user puts the snippet in place, when they use the iframe for example, the URL referenced in the iframe must contain the identifier.

Not sure what your server-side technologies are, but generally this concept works across the board:

For example... your server saves this information in its database:

```
user-example-domain.com,19850979
```

Your user's iframe ( which you generate and give them ) references:

```
your-serving-domain.com/iframeloader/19850979
```

Now, in the code that handles `/iframeloader/` and receives `19850979` as the identifier, compare the hostname of the referrer. This is the `Referer` header, which is an HTTP header field:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

If the hostname of the referrer is value, continue loading the iframe. If not, abort and show some kind of informative error message.